# Set Snapshot isolation is not reflecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

When I ran - SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT -Command successfully executed But the below query returns :

```
SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on,
       snapshot_isolation_state_desc,
       snapshot_isolation_state
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  name = 'MyDB'
```

Output:

```
is_read_committed_snapshot_on   0
snapshot_isolation_state_desc   OFF 
snapshot_isolation_state        0
```

Could you pleae let me know why the set transction command is not reflecting?
Also, I assume `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is already "on" as my "`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` "command runs successfully.Is that correct?

Answer (score 13):

No snapshot isolation is not on for that database.

If you try and then run a query against that database you will get the message.

> Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'MyDB'
>   because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER
>   DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation.

To enable it you need to run

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

Comment: Thanks .I am not getting any such message when I ran SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT .It ran sucessfully.That is why I am confused.

Comment: @Ikrishs - It isn't an error. `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT; SELECT * FROM master..spt_monitor` would have worked fine as the transaction doesn't touch anything in the DB where it is disabled.

Comment: Thanks.It throws following error only after the select statement ."Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'xyz' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation." Hence Set Transcation Snapshot will not check if Allow_Snapshot_On is already on or not.

Comment: @martinsmith tanks , grate, + 1 for i Was facing this from last 3 hrs. ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON; works